# Java Вывести на экран содержимое каталога со всеми его подкаталогами

Tags: java, файлы

Есть папка с музыкой (music). В ней еще одна папка, тоже с музыкой. Задача программы прочитать все, что есть в папке music (включая содержимое подпапок) и вывести на экран.

Проблема в том, что я разобрался как читать только "главный" каталог, но не содержимое его подкаталогов.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = null;
    File dir = new File("C:/music");
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        for (File item : dir.listFiles()) {
            if (item.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println(item.getName() + "  каталог");
                //как написать "если есть каталог, то прочитать его содержимое"?
            } else {
                System.out.println(item.getName() + " файл");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Буду очень признателен за наглядный пример.

Answer (score 3):

Создать метод который будет работать рекурсивно, как то так:

```
public static void readFiles(File baseDirectory){
    if (baseDirectory.isDirectory()){
        for (File file : baseDirectory.listFiles()) {
            if(file.isFile()){
                System.out.println(file.getName() + " файл");
            }else {
                System.out.println(file.getName() + " каталог");
                readFiles(file);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: так-то более менее понятно, только вот куда прописывать путь к каталогу?

Comment: В main методет вызови метод который выше, и в него передай свой файл  `File dir = new File("C:/music"); readFiles(dir);`

Answer (score 0):

В Java 8 есть `Files.walk` (вы ведь используете Java 8?:)):

```
Files.walk(Paths.get("C:\music"), FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS)
.map(Path::toFile)
.forEach(f -> {
    System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath() + (f.isDirectory() ? " каталог" : " файл"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Продолжу мысль @iksuy

```
Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get(fileName), new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(dir);
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

можно использовать org.apache.commons::commons-io

```
FileUtils.listFiles(File directory, String[] extensions, boolean recursive);
```

пример:

```
List<File> files = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(new File("C:\\temp"), null, true);
files.forEach(System.out::println);
```